# Storing 1|2|3 as integer in MySQL via Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to store this type of integers "4|8|128" into the integer column in MySQL via sequelize.

In MYSQL, i can do so using raw queries.

```
How can I do so using sequelize without writing it as raw queries?

Reference: https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3359321/Storing-Multiple-Statuses-Using-an-Integer-Column.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine when the values are integers:

```
    myTestModel.update({
        funkyField : 4 | 8 | 128
        }, 
        {where : {id : 1}
        });
```

What did you try?

Comment: Let me try it out